# firefox - deny access to menus

Tags: firefox, kde

I'm preparing a presentation. I will use wordpress on localhost for this. Then the visitors will have access to the mouse and see the displayed site.

I'm afraid people can somehow get access to my local files, e.g. when they click the File->Open File dialog or when they right click with the mouse, select 'View page source' and then click 'save page as', they can:

1. overwrite my files
2. see file names

Do you have any ideas how can I limit such access by e.g. hiding the app menu (File, Edit, View) and disabling menu on click? 
Is my aim clear?
I was thinking about creating a new xul app or modifying firefox UI. Any hints, other browser?

You can think that the user can still close the app and can have access to my desktop. I use kde and to block such behavior I will remove the titlebar, disable global shortcuts and force window to be maximized. I can do it by pressing (alt-f3->more actions->special window settings).
If you have any other hints I should be aware of, pls let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various **kiosk** add-ons available for Firefox. I would recommend [Open Kiosk](https://www.mozdevgroup.com/products/openkioskdistro.html) however. It's based on Firefox but purpose-built for creating a secure locked-down kiosk.