# Locking down a Windows 7 PC to just a browser

Tags: security, kiosk

I have been tasked with building several PCs to act as secure kiosks that allow users to view and use an intranet site at my company.

- Our LP staff will cover physical security, so that is not a concern.
- To prevent booting from a USB drive or walking with the HDD, I will be encrypting with BitLocker.

What I am having trouble with is deciding on a method to lock down Windows 7 in such a way that the only thing a user has access to is a browser (in this case, IE9) and limit the browser to specific URLs (or domains).

I have considered doing this through Group Policy, but it seems there would be a substantial amount of research, development, and testing involved to get it right. With that said, does anyone know of a free or inexpensive piece of software that can accomplish this? Any recommendations would be appreciated.

Comment: Windows 8.1 will have a "Kiosk Mode" or "Assigned Access" which will do exactly this. Consider it if the benefits (OS-level support) can outweigh the wait (It's supposed to be out in the last quarter of 2013 or so) for you.

Comment: Have you considered building your own Embedded Standard/Industry system? You can restrict access to features by just not installing them. 
https://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/products-solutions-overview.aspx

Comment: Darth Android -- Windows 8 kiosk mode is compelling. Unfortunately I need to have these deployed sooner than that. Szymon Szydelko -- I had not considered that, but given the small # of systems I need to build and the short turnaround time, I don't think the time investment would be worth it. Interesting, though.

Comment: @Chck: Does the browser have to be IE? Otherwise I would recommend [this](http://superuser.com/a/608087/138343).

Comment: Karen -- Unfortunately, yes. The vendor of the intranet site in question will only support IE9.

Comment: @Chck - If thats the case then Windows 8 isn't even an option.  Windows 7 has tons of kiosk applications thats exist you should go that route instead.  If you want native support Windows 8.1 will be your ultimate solution once IE9 requirement isn't an issue.

Comment: Ramhound -- Thank you, I hadn't thought of IE9 not being supported in Windows 8.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/107611/how-can-i-start-up-windows-without-explorer-loading-up?rq=1

Comment: If not for the IE requirement, I would have said Chromebook ftw. Sigh.

Comment: `iexplore.exe -k` *`[website address]`*

Answer (score 4):

Group Policy is how either you or a piece of software will need to get this done. Linked is 2 documents; [Creating a Steady State by Using Microsoft Technologies](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24373)  and [Group Policy Settings for Creating a Steady State](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3118) showing/explaining how to configure per user or machine to lock down the options you desire.

Comment: I have downloaded both and am reviewing them. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of kiosk software available to do this, I have used and can recommend [SiteKiosk](http://www.sitekiosk.com/SiteKiosk/Default.aspx) although I can't say if it is better or worse than others.

Many of the different vendors offer Free Trials, so [check a few out](https://www.google.com/#sugexp=cpsugrpqhmsignedin&gs_rn=18&gs_ri=psy-ab&tok=5dBAJRuNjxG3Usq08T4eeg&cp=7&gs_id=is&xhr=t&q=kiosk+software&es_nrs=true&pf=p&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&oq=kiosk+s&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48572450,d.dmQ&fp=c17de55b5a7af543&biw=1920&bih=924)

There also is [OpenKiosk](http://openkiosk.sourceforge.net/work.html), an Open Source alternative.

Another real good choice appears to [Webconverger](http://webconverger.com/) which claims to be a Browser Only Operating System. In practice it appears to be a micro-linux, and I am not sure what customization is available.

Comment: SiteKiosk looks good, but the price is a bit heavy. That's what I was really looking for with my question: Recommendations from people who have actually used the software. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I googled `lock down kiosk windows 7` and found these softwares. Seems legit and pretty solid.

**Internet Kiosk Pro** (http://www.emailarms.com/products/internet_kiosk.html)

**Advanced Internet Kiosk** (http://www.softstack.com/advink.html)

**Secure Lockdown** (http://shop.inteset.com/Products/21-lock-down-windows-7-and-run-internet-explorer-as-a-customized-kiosk-application.aspx)

**Sitekiosk** (http://www.sitekiosk.com/SiteKiosk/Default.aspx)

Or as Dark mentioned in the comments, there is a built in Kiosk mode into WIndows 8.1. If you can put this project on hold until the official release, this may give you the functionality that you're wanting without having to purchase third-party software.

[image]

Of course, if you can move away from Windows for the kiosk, you can use an open source alternative.

http://webconverger.com/

Comment: I'm really looking for recommendations from people who have used the software. Thank you for your response, though.

Answer (score 0):

Can't recommend [WINSelect](http://www.faronics.com/products/winselect/) Enough. Worth the money easily.